# Como fazer que abra um Pop-up ao apertar um botão?

Tags: php, popup

Quero colocar uma janela pop-up ao apertar o botão frete, onde abre uma página que a pessoa coloca o cep e é calculado o frete do produto, como se faz isso?
Se alguém puder me ajudar nessa do frete também agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo utilizar a biblioteca [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

No link mostra como utilizar a biblioteca e tambám tem algumas demos.

Answer (score 0):

Ta ai, JSS, CSS e HTML. pra conseguir um HTML para o calculo do frete utilize o site http://www.frete-facil.com/

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btnFrete").click(function() {
        $("#registerDiv").fadeIn(1000);
        $("body").append("<div id='mask'></div>");
        $("#mask").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#popup").fadeIn(1000);
    });

});
```

```css
.input{
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.required{
  color:red;
  font-size:12px;
}

#registerDiv{
  display:none;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  border:2px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
  background:#cdcdcd;
  width:280px;
  text-align:center;
}
#popup{
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
  background:#969696;
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:25%;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:100%;
  
}
#popupinfo{
  padding:2px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#cfcfcf;
}
#popupinfo p{
  font-size:14px;
}

#popupinfo .button {
  text-align:center;
}
#popupinfo .button a{
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #333;
  width:20px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#1A1A1A;
  color:#eee;
}

#popupinfo .button a:hover{
  background:#eee;
  color:#1a1a1a;
}

#mask{
  
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 999;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnFrete" value="Calcular frete" />
<div id="popup">
  <div id="popupinfo">
    <div id="registerDiv">
      <p class="required">
        Coloque o HTML do calculo de frete aqui
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```